# I am getting the error : The argument type 'QuerySnapshot <Map<String , dymanic>>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<object>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error : The argument type 'QuerySnapshot <Map<String , dymanic>>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot'

```
    body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: firestoreDb,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return CustomeCard(snapshot: snapshot.data, index: index,); 
                });
          }),
    );
  }
```

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final QuerySnapshot snapshot;
  final int index;

  const CustomeCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snapshot,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [Text(snapshot.docs[index]['title'])],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include firestoreDb ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.